# How can a module be forcefully loaded using Spring XD REST interface?

Tags: rest, spring-xd

I want to upload a module to a Spring XD installation using the REST interface it provides. If the module is brand new, it works as expected. If the module was previously registered, though, the command will fail (again, as expected).

I understand it would be conceptually simple to delete the module and upload it again. The problem with that is that the module is configured by means of a .properties file, under the XD_MODULE_CONFIG_LOCATION hierarchy. Actually, the presence of this file is hindering my ability to delete the module, even if using the xd-shell!

The xd-shell command provides a '--force' option to 'module upload', that solves the problem. Is there any equivalence when using the POST method to register the module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at the REST controller for module upload and it looks like adding `?force=true` to the URI will do it.

Yes; that's what the shell does:

```
String uriTemplate = resources.get("modules").toString() + "/{type}/{name}?force={force}";
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Gary!
I should have had the same realisation by myself!  :)  I was getting a 500 response from the server, with body:
`[
  {
    "logref": "RuntimeException",
    "message": "Error trying to save Uploaded module 'processor:xdc-prices-processor'",
    "links": []
  }
]`
and I blindly assumed the problem was the server ignoring the force=true argument.